# If $(a_n)$ is a sequence such that $a_n=a_{f(n)}+a_{g(n)}$, where $\lim \frac{f(n)}{n}+\lim\frac{g(n)}{n}<1$, can we claim that $\lim\frac{a_n}{n}=0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, inequality

The inspiration for this question came with an attempt to solve [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3819402/help-with-sequence-question-involving-floor-function).

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers satisfying $a_n = a_{f(n)} + a_{g(n)}~\forall n\in\Bbb{N}$, where $f, g: \Bbb{N}\rightarrow \Bbb{N}$ are functions such that $\begin{aligned}\lim \frac{f(n)}{n}+\lim\frac{g(n)}{n}<1\end{aligned}$. Can we claim that $\begin{aligned}\lim\frac{a_n}{n} = 0\end{aligned}$ (i.e., that this sequence grows slower than any linear function)?

I know the statement is true if we assume that the limit exists. In fact, if $\begin{aligned}\lim\frac{a_n}{n} = \alpha\end{aligned}$, then

$$\alpha = \lim\frac{a_n}{n} = \lim \frac{a_{f(n)}+a_{g(n)}}{n} = \lim \Big(\frac{f(n)}{n}\frac{a_{f(n)}}{f(n)}+\frac{g(n)}{n}\frac{a_{g(n)}}{g(n)}\Big) = \alpha\Big( \lim \frac{f(n)}{n}+\lim\frac{g(n)}{n}\Big)$$

Because $\begin{aligned}\lim \frac{f(n)}{n}+\lim\frac{g(n)}{n}\neq 1\end{aligned}$ we have $\alpha = 0$. Therefore, it remains to be seen whether the limit really exists.

My ideia was to try to show that the sequence $\begin{aligned}\Big(\frac{a_n}{n}\Big)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}\end{aligned}$ is decreasing from a certain point, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What limit is this? For example, is it $\lim_{n \to \infty} \text{or} \lim_{n \to 0}$ or something else?

Comment: @personcallednothing all limits refer to $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$

Answer (score 5):

Your claim about the limit of $b_n=\dfrac{a_n}{n}$ is indeed true. Here is a proof.

Choose $\alpha,\beta$ with $\lim \dfrac{f(n)}{n} \lt \alpha$, $\lim \dfrac{g(n)}{n} \lt \beta$ and $\alpha+\beta \lt 1$.

By the definition of a limit, there is a $N$ such that $f(n)\lt \alpha n$
and $g(n)\lt \beta n$ for $n\geq N$.

Let $N_0=\max\left(N,\dfrac{1}{1-\alpha},\dfrac{1}{1-\beta}\right)$. Then for $n\geq N_0$, we have $\alpha n \leq n-1$ whence $f(n) \leq n-1$ ; similarly $g(n) \leq n-1$, so that

$$
f(n) \lt n,~ g(n) \lt n \ (n\geq N_0) \tag{1}
$$

On the other hand, from $n\geq N_0 \geq \dfrac{1}{1-\alpha} \geq \dfrac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}$ we deduce $n\geq \dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{\alpha}-1}$ or $n\big(\frac{1}{\alpha}-1\big)\geq 1$, so that $\left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{\alpha}\right\rfloor \geq n+1$, and hence

$$
\left\lfloor\frac{n}{\alpha}\right\rfloor \gt n,~ \left\lfloor\frac{n}{\beta}\right\rfloor \gt n \ (n\geq N_0) \tag{2}
$$

It follows from $(1)$ that

$$
|b_n|=\left|\frac{f(n)}{n}b_{f(n)}+\frac{g(n)}{n}b_{g(n)}\right| \leq
(\alpha + \beta) \max(|b_{f(n)}|,|b_{g(n)}|) \ (n\geq N_0) \tag{3}
$$

Let $M=\max\big(|b_k|\ : \ 1 \leq k \leq N_0\big)$ and $N_1=\left\lfloor \dfrac{N_0}{\max(\alpha,\beta)}\right\rfloor=\min\left(\left\lfloor \dfrac{N_0}{\alpha}\right\rfloor,\left\lfloor \dfrac{N_0}{\beta}\right\rfloor\right)$. By $(2)$, we have $N_2 \gt N_1$. Let $n\in [N_0,N_1]$. Then $f(n)\leq \alpha n \leq \alpha N_1 \leq N_0$ and hence  $|b_{f(n)}|\leq M$ ; similarly $|b_{g(n)}|\leq M$. Combining this with $(3)$, we deduce

$$
 |b_n| \leq (\alpha+\beta) M \ (n \in [N_0,N_1]) \tag{4}
$$

Since $(\alpha+\beta) M \lt M$, we see that $M$ is also equal to $\max\big(|b_k| \ : \ 1 \leq k \leq N_1\big)$, and the argument we have just made can be repeated with $N_1$ in place of $N_0$ ; we then deduce $|b_n| \leq (\alpha+\beta) M$ for $n\in [N_1,N_2]$ where $N_2=\left\lfloor \dfrac{N_1}{\min(\alpha,\beta)}\right\rfloor \gt N_1$. Iterating this argument, it is now clear that

$$
\forall n \geq N_0, |b_n| \leq (\alpha+\beta) M  \tag{4'}
$$

Combining $(4')$ with the definition of $M$, we see that

$$
\forall n \in {\mathbb N}, |b_n| \leq M \tag{5}
$$

We can now revisit $(3)$ and strengthen it. Suppose that for some $T\geq N_0$ and $\varepsilon >0$ we have

$$
\forall n \geq T, |b_n| \leq \varepsilon \tag{6}
$$

We can then deduce the following. Let $n\in{\mathbb N}$. If $f(n)\leq T$, then $|b_{f(n)}| \leq M$ and hence $\left|\dfrac{a_{f(n)}}{n}\right| \leq \dfrac{Mf(n)}{n} \leq \dfrac{MT}{n}$. If, on the other hand, $f(n) \geq T$, then $|b_{f(n)}| \leq \varepsilon$ by $(6)$, whence $\left|\dfrac{a_{f(n)}}{n}\right| \leq \dfrac{Mf(n)}{n} \leq \alpha\varepsilon$ (it is here that we use the hypothesis $T\geq N_0$). In both cases, we have $\left|\dfrac{a_{f(n)}}{n}\right| \leq \max\left(\dfrac{MT}{n},\alpha\varepsilon\right)$ and similarly $\left|\dfrac{a_{g(n)}}{n}\right| \leq \max\left(\dfrac{MT}{n},\beta\varepsilon\right)$. Combining the two, we have

$$
\forall n \in {\mathbb N}, |b_n| \leq  \left|\frac{a_{f(n)}}{n}\right|+\left|\frac{a_{g(n)}}{n}\right|
\leq \max\left(\frac{MT}{n},\alpha\varepsilon\right) + \max\left(\frac{MT}{n},\beta\varepsilon\right)
\tag{7}
$$

For large enough $n$, the RHS of (7) reduces to $(\alpha+\beta)\varepsilon$ ; in other words,

$$
\forall n \geq T', |b_n| \leq (\alpha+\beta)\varepsilon \ \left(\textrm{where} \ T'=\frac{MT}{\min(\alpha,\beta)\varepsilon}\right)\tag{6'}
$$

Then, if we define a sequence $(T_k)_{k\geq 1}$ with $T_1=N_0$ and $T_{k+1}=\left\lceil\dfrac{MT_k}{\min(\alpha,\beta)}\right\rceil$ then we have

$$
\forall n \geq T_k, |b_n| \leq M(\alpha+\beta)^k  \tag{8}
$$

The proof of $(8)$ is by induction on $k$ : the base case follows from $(5)$, and the induction step is a special case of  the implication $(6) \Rightarrow (6')$ that we have just shown (with $\varepsilon = M(\alpha+\beta)^k$). This shows that $(b_n)\to 0$ as wished.